# Curve Fitting for multiple scatter plot from different csv dataset

Tags: python

I have successfully plotted multiple scatter plot from different dataset into a plot with the figure below.

The next agenda is curve fitting for this scatter plots and then proceeding to analyze using regression analysis[image]

Can anyone help with a code to achieve a curve fitting?

Comment: Please provide more information. What is your specific problem? If you don't know where to start at all, you should try to look into how to perform linear regression, using for example [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html).

Comment: The problem is how to do a curve for a multiple scatter plot, after which I intend to analyse using a regression model, but first I need to actualize the curve fitting. Thanks

Comment: Break it down into smaller problems. Do the fitting for one of the curves, then proceed to the next.

Comment: Let me try and revert back. Thanks